# Google Play hero slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A client has expressed that they really like how Google Play handles their hero slider. I've tried replicating the effect in jQueryCycle to no avail. Can anyone shed some light on the best way to achieve the same effect?

For those unfamiliar: https://play.google.com/store?hl=en - the slider shows a centralized "current slider" as well as a "previous" and "next" slide preview shown behind a screen. It's continuous and you can always see a before and after.

Answer (score 1):

It's not continuous. Stuff on the right doesn't slide in between slides, it just appears. It's not exactly setting the bar high for carousels.

All you really need is any old carousel split into 3 segments with translucent overlays permanently over segments 1 and 3 and one that flips on and off over segment 2. Every time a slide completes, hide the #2 overlay. Every time one begins show it again.

Stuff you'll want to know:

- Rooting absolute elements to relative positioned elements with CSS so you can fix absolute panels over the content stuff without affecting layout.
- Using callbacks or custom events with jQuery.
- How to make transparent/translucent .png images with Photoshop to use as panel backgrounds.

Comment: So I'm assuming the easiest route will to be build a custom slider instead of editing/hacking an existing plugin? The first and third "stuff to knows" are in the bag no problem but will need to get a team member to help with the second. Thanks for your answer!